# why does this blit from a numpy array to a pygame surface leak memory?

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

```
def blit_convert(dst_sfc, board):
    dst_ary = pg.surfarray.pixels2d(dst_sfc)
    src_ary = np.asarray(board, dtype=np.uint8)
    dst_ary[...] = src_ary
    del src_ary
    del dst_ary
```

is called with:

```
dst_sfc = pg.Surface((width, height), 0, 8)
board = np.zeros((width, height), dtype=np.uint16)
```

python 2.5.2, pygame 1.7.1release, numpy 1.1.0

---

changing:

```
src_ary = np.asarray(board, dtype=np.uint8)
```

to:

```
src_ary = board.astype(np.uint8)
```

slows the memory leak by 42%

Comment: If it helps debug things, `np.asarray` will avoid making a copy, if possible, while `board.astype(np.uint8)` will always make a copy. However, in this case, they should both return a copy, as the dtypes don't match. Numpy 1.1 is rather ancient, though you may not have control over that, of course. Can you try upgrading to a more recent version of numpy and/or pygame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pygame 1.7.1 uses`Numeric` and doing `dst_ary[...] = src_ary` where `dst_ary` is a `Numeric.array` and `src_ary` is a `numpy.ndarray` leaks memory for some unknown reason.

Upgrading pygame to 1.9.1 which can use numpy for surface access fixes this.